# INPUT MANAGEMENT IN REACT FORM

Tags: reactjs, state, use-state, use-reducer

i'm coding a dynamic react form. I want to be able to print a field value, update the state according to it's value changes, and all of that while i'm typing inside that field. I also want to print the state in the console by clicking on the submit button. Not that hard, i know, and i did it (almost perfect). Here is how i did :

- i declared and initial state, with inside and object called "inputs", with 3 attributes, name, email and password.
- i declared my reducer with one switch case, with the action type "SETINPUTS", that returns the state and its inputs object set to the action payload.
- i declared a constant "inputs" assigned to a useState with initial value set to the initial state.inputs.
- i declared a "state" constant assigned to a useReducer initialized with my initial state.
- then, i declared two functions : handleChange() that update "inputs"(useState const) and dispatch the "SETINPUTS" action with a payload equal to "inputs"; handleSubmit() that prevent the default event of submitting and print the state in the console.
- and, at last, for each field, i set the value attribute to the corresponding "inputs" value and the onChange to the   handleChange() function.

here is my code itself :

> ```
> import React, { useReducer, useState } from 'react'
> import './Form.css'
>
> const initialState = {
>   inputs : {
>     name: "",
>     email: "",
>     password: ""
>   }
> };
> const reducer = (state, action) => {
>   switch(action.type){
>     case 'SETINPUTS' :
>       return { ...state, inputs: action.payload };
>     default: 
>       return state;
>   }
> }
>
> const Form = () => {
>
>   const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(initialState.inputs)
>
>   const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
>   
>   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
>     e.preventDefault();
>     console.log(state)
>   } 
>
>   function handleChange(e){
>     setInputs({ ...inputs, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
>     dispatch({ type: 'SETINPUTS', payload: inputs })
>   }
>
>   return (
>     <div className='form'>
>       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
>         <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
>         <input 
>           type="text" 
>           name='name' 
>           placeholder='John Doe'
>           value={inputs.name}
>           onChange={handleChange}
>         />
>         <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
>         <input 
>           type="email" 
>           name='email' 
>           placeholder='johndoe09@example.ex' 
>           value={inputs.email}
>           onChange={handleChange}
>         />
>         <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
>         <input 
>           type="password" 
>           name='password' 
>           placeholder='enter your password please'
>           value={inputs.password}
>           onChange={handleChange}
>         />
>         <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
>       </form>
>       <div>
>         {state.inputs.name} {state.inputs.email} {state.inputs.password}
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   )
> }
>
> export default Form
> ```

The problem, as you can see on this picture, is that what i type is not exactly what is returned or print in the console. i have to delete the last letter, to add a space for the last letter to be taken into account. When i delete the last character, it remains, etc ... It's quite strange, i need your help please.

THANKS A LOT :) !

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is with your **handleChange** method. Setting state is a async method... so you will not get the latest value in state.
Try below implementation:

```
function handleChange(e) {
    setInputs({ ...inputs, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "SETINPUTS", payload: inputs });
  }, [inputs]);
```

or this one:

```
function handleChange(e) {
    setInputs({ ...inputs, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    dispatch({
      type: "SETINPUTS",
      payload: {
        ...inputs,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `handleChange` function, `setInputs` is an async operation, meaning the `dispatch` call will not be using the latest state of inputs.

You could instead pass in `e.target.value` directly:

```
function handleChange(e){
    setInputs({ ...inputs, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    dispatch({ type: 'SETINPUTS', payload: {...inputs, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }});
}
```

However, you may want to rethink your design to depend either on the component's state, or the reducer store only, rather than having both and trying to keep them in sync.